# What is the best sorting algorithm for a array with max elements in a specified range

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Let's I have to sort an array with 85% elements lying in the range 1 to 50 and the remaining 15% in the range 51 to 5000. Which sorting algorithm will sort this array most efficiently with least time complexity and space complexity?

Comment: do you have any space complexity limitations?

Comment: @pavel.lazar Yes, It should occupy least space or it can be easily done by taking another and counting occurence of each element.

Comment: The question needs to specify how algorithms are to be compared, such as `a` and `b`, with goal of minimizing `a` times time complexity plus `b` times space complexity.

Comment: after some searching around this seems like a good fit for radix sort: https://brilliant.org/wiki/radix-sort/ however @rcgldr point is valid

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort is one option even if all elements range between 1 and 5000.

you might want however to use counting sort to any element that is <= 50 and create another array with remaining elements and use a quick sort on that one and then append the quick sort result to the array sorted with count sort since all those values will be larger than the ones in the first array, but I don't think this will give you much gain in performance

Comment: @rcgldr that was pretty much my point unless there are some space complexity limitations